# Testing if the directory of a file is writable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to check to see if the directory of a file given is writable or not.

```
fullPATH=$(realpath "$1")
echo "realpath => $fullPATH"
pathDIR=${fullPATH%/*}
echo "pathDIR => $pathDIR"

if [ ! -w "$pathDIR" ]; then
    echo $1 is a file in a directory that is not writeable.
#   return 1
else
    echo writable
fi
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing things up in the test as far as formatting the path that comes from pathDIR but I can't figure out what to do there.

Comment: why is it that things seem to all of a sudden work when I post a question?

Comment: Pretty sure that what I wrote is the answer to what I was trying to do.  Sorry to waste anyone's time.  Hopefully it will be of  help to anyone else looking for that issue.

Comment: That's the real value of creating a MCVE. A lot of the time, you'll realize either what the problem is, or that it's somewhere else. ^^

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend using `$(dirname "$fullPATH")` instead of `${fullPATH%/*}` -- there are some edge cases (like fullPATH="/file.txt") that it handles better.

Answer (score 1):

on if statement you must us $fullPATH

```
if [ ! -w "$fullPATH" ]
```

try it

```
    # /bin/bash
fullPATH=$(realpath "$1")
echo "realpath => $fullPATH"
pathDIR=${fullPATH%/*}
echo "pathDIR => $fullPATH"

if [ ! -w "$fullPATH" ]
 then
    echo $1 is a file in a directory that is not writeable.
#   return 1
else
    echo writable
fi
```